# Segmentation fault with Selection Sort recursive functions

Tags: c, function, debugging, pointers, recursion

For class I have to make a Selection Sort function recursively with no loops. I finally got it to compile with no errors, but now it just says "segmentation fault (core dumped)". I'm pretty new to C so please explain what this means. I'm assuming that there's a stack overflow, but I can't see where or how.

Here are my two functions involved in Selection Sort.

```
void CheckRemaining(int arr[], int minpos, int len, int j) {
    if (j == len - 1) {
        return;
    }

    if (arr[minpos] > arr[j]) {
        minpos = j;
    }

    CheckRemaining(arr, minpos,len, j + 1); //j increments with each iteration
}

void SelectionSort(int arr[], int len) {
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int minpos;

    minpos = i;
    if (i == len - 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        j = i;
        CheckRemaining(arr, minpos,len, j);
        swap(&arr[minpos], &arr[j]);

        SelectionSort(&arr[i++], len); //The location in the array increments
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int len;

    int arr[] = {5,7,3,2,9,4,10};
    len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    SelectionSort(arr,len);

    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something big here?

Comment: How do you initially call the `SelectionSort` function? Can you perhaps create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: what error are you getting? infinite loop?

Comment: Also, you *have* tried running in a debugger to catch the crash? Where in your code does the crash happen? What's the values of the involved variables?

Comment: Try to set some breakpoints and provide some code that actually compiles.

Comment: `SelectionSort(&arr[i++], len);` meant `SelectionSort(&arr[0], len);` This is the same every time call. and `minpos` not change by `CheckRemaining`.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely correct that you have a stack overflow, because the recursion will never end.

The problem is that you use the local variable `i` in the condition to terminate the recursion, but you forget that local variables are local for each call. Every time the `SelectionSort` is called, there will be a new `i` variable initialized to zero, so the recursion will never end.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have a segmentation fault anymore! However, it is not outputting a sorted array so I will double check my logic

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectionSort(&arr[i++], len);
```

I think, it should not work for this code. The recursion will never end. Every time you are calling to ***SelectionSort()*** and initializing ***i*** with 0. So ***i*** will never be ***len-2***. Each time this function is getting a different **i**.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
```

You defined i as a local scope variable, meaning that every time is called, i=0 is taking effect, preventing you from ever having any i greater then 0, thus this condition:

```
if (i==len-2)
```

will never be true. Hence, you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, to answer to you about the segfault, when you have a segmentation fault, it means that you wanna reach a "forbidden" memory area, for example (usual error in beginning) when you didn't malloc'd a string/tab and your loop's index is "too far" you want to access to a "forbidden" area then it segfault.